# Pillow & Tkinter doesn't show PNGs with transparency

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter, png, python-imaging-library

My application was recently working fine, but when I upgraded Python to v3.7.2, which solved another problem I was having, the images are either no longer shown or of poor quality.

After doing some testing, I've concluded that I can display any PNG without transparency, but PNGs with transparency exhibit this problem. I can recreate it with this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
path = 'png-transparent.png'
img = Image.open(path)
imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
panel = tk.Label(root, image=imgtk).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

If I use a label to display the image, it doesn't show at all. If I use a button to display the image, which is what I really need to do, it is poor quality (which means not displaying properly, no definition, coarse edges).

They are very small (16x16), but you can see two different icons here, the ones in the boxes are the distorted ones and the ones not in boxes are how they are supposed to look.

[image: Bin-distorted] [image: Bin-normal] [image: Plus-distorted] [image: Plus-normal]

Current versions: Python 3.7.2, Pillow 5.4.1, OS X 10.13.6

Comment: Please upload and add a link to the image to your question. Also note that the value assigned to `panel` will be `None` because the `pack()` method doesn't return a value.

Comment: Edited the post to add an image.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure that image has some transparent areas because it doesn't look like it does in my image editor (Photoshop)—it appears to be a 24-bit RGB image (i.e. has 3 x 8-bit channels) as opposed to a 4-channel RGBA image (one that also has an "alpha" channel).

Comment: Edited to show original un-edited correct images. The distorted buttons are screenshots.

Comment: That's better—those originals are what I sought.

Comment: Both of those two original images seem to work properly for me. I'm using Python 3.7.2, Pillow 5.4.1, on Windows 7 Pro. Seems like I've seen numerous questions here about difficulties using Python on Macos (because the OS comes with some version of it), so perhaps the upgrade you did messed-up your custom Python installation.

Comment: That's it! Re-installed and (nearly) everything is fine. Thanks.